# texts and elements in div part are not aligning at the center of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

h1 and p tags inside the class center are not aligning to the center. I have tried various combinations of codes but nothing worked.

**this is my html code** This html code was copied from bootstrap website and I did a bit of editing for my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>     <meta charset="utf-8">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/technical_landing.css">    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">   <title>Minimum Bootstrap HTML Skeleton</title>

    <!--  -->

    <style>

    </style>    

</head>

<body>

     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Technical lab</a>   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>   </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
      </li>


    </ul>    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>   </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
      </li>


    </ul>
      </div> </nav>   </div> </nav>

    <div class="container center">  <div class="row">
        <div class="<col-md-12>">
            <h2>
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="far fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-stack-1x"></i>
                </span>
            </h2>
            <h1>Technical lab is coming soon.</h1>
            <p>Waiting is not easy but just wait this time</p>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
            <i class="fas fa-spinner"></i>
            <br>Click me</button>


        </div>  </div>  </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**This is css code is my css part please check .center part in this. I have tried many codes to bring those elements in center of the page but nothing worked for me.**

```
    /*<!--https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537498425277-c283d32ef9db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80-->*/

html{
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand{
    color: black;
}

body{
     background:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80)
    no-repeat center center fixed ;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: catamaran;
}



    .center{

        text-align: center; 
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:5%;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;  



    }

.navbar{
    height: 45px;
}

h1,p{
    color: black;

}

h2>span{
    color: black;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    h1 {
        background-color: #449d44;
    }
    h2{
        background-color: #449d44;
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px)    {
    h1{
        background-color:skyblue;
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the screenshot the page]

Comment: Just a small typo I think.  <div class="<col-md-12>"> should be like <div class="col-md-12">. If you change that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So you can see that the text is aligned but not aligned on the center of the screen, the reason being is it looks like the width of the div needs to be set to 100%.

Try adding width: 100% to the .center class.